# How do I make the WPF TextBox border inside the ScrollViewer not disappear

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, scrollviewer

in a WPF window I have a TextBox inside a ScrollViewer:

```xml
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" MaxHeight="160" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBox MinHeight="80" Name="generalLog"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With an empty text it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbEyu.png).

When the text gets to long or contains too many lines, the scrollbars appear, as they should. But as the TextBox is wrapped inside the ScrollViewer, the TextBox gets bigger and its border (default style) gets hidden on the sides:

[Link to Screenshot because I can't embed pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8PC4.png)

As you can see, the border is not visible on the left side.
Is there any way to make the ScrollViewer appear inside the TextBox? Or make the ScrollViewer have a border like the TextBox and hide the TextBox one, which would probably look the way I want.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Scrollviewer with a border and set Textbox borderbrush="transparent" ?

```xml
<Border>
  <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" MaxHeight="160" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
   <TextBox BorderBrush="transparent" MinHeight="80" Name="generalLog"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```